# Synchronising browser events in JS

Tags: javascript, events, asynchronous

This is a bit of an abstract question, but I've been pondering its usefulness, and maybe it's either already been solved or inspires someone to do something based on it.

Well recently I ran across an issue whereby three browser events were fired, all as the result of a single user interaction: click, blur and focus. When the user clicks from one input to another, these events occur; and a similar set occur when the user tabs from one to another.

The trouble I had was that they fired in this order: blur, focus, click. It meant that, if the blur event caused DOM changes, the click event could be affected. I really wanted click, blur, focus - but that's not what the browser gave me.

I figured a general utility could be produced, capturing and cancelling browser events, then synchronising them and firing a single handler for all three. Perhaps extending the Event class so that the event could be reinstated.

Is there a more abstract design pattern I can use here? Something that will allow me to set up an arbitrary number of event listeners, and then fire a single event when all are complete? Does it have an implementation already? All advice welcome.

Comment: Yes, you could implement your abstract listener. But please define what should happen when they are not triggered by the same action (which probably could only be implemented as "firing in a short timespan together" anyway), e.g. a blur event from focusing a different element than you're interested in, or by doing so without a click.

Answer (score 0):

Dont need to break head around this! you can always trigger these events Programmatically

Note: `object` referenced here is any element selected using javascript selector.

Initially `onBlur` & `onFocus` do `event.preventDefault` which allows `onClick` to do its job first

```
var clicked=false;
object.onblur = function(e) {
    if (!clicked) {
        e.preventDefault
    }
};

object.onfocus = function(e) {
    if (!clicked) {
        e.preventDefault
    }
};
```

inside click event undo the above preventions and trigger the events in the order you wanted

```
object.onclick=function(){
clicked=true;
//Do anything
object.unbind('blur'); //this do undo prevent default
object.unbind('focus'); //this do undo prevent default

object.blur(); //in order you want
object.focus(); 

//make sure to put condition if click clicked
};
```

Thats it ! Hope it helps